# Why is my PHP Array not working?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to add a promotion section in a shopping cart. It is a temp hack but the code is not working.

```
/cart.php?promocode=1&productcode=434_red
// WILL ECHO NO


/cart.php?promocode=sale20&productcode=555_red
// WILL ECHO YES BUT NOT WORKING
```

This is the PHP code, I have broken it all down and I am thinking something to do with my `&&` or `in_array` ?? Appreciate help.

```
<?
// PROMO CODE
$promocode=$_GET["promocode"];
$productcode=$_GET["productcode"];

// SALE LIST (ONLY SALE20 WORKS ON THIS)
$saleitemlist=array("555_red, 305_black, 582_elecblue, 593_black");

// PROMO CODE VALIDATION CHECK

// ALLOW EXISTING CODES TO WORK
if($promocode=="chocolate2" || $promocode=="post") {
        $promocode_validate_check = $_POST['promocode']; // APPLY CART FUNCTION
    } else {
        // NOT AN EXISTING CODE - IF SALE20, APPLY THE CODE OTHERWISE DO NOTHING
        if($promocode=="sale20" && in_array($productcode, $saleitemlist)) {
            $promocode_validate_check = $_POST['promocode']; // APPLY CART FUNCTION
            echo "YES"; 
        } else {
            echo "NO";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it isn't array you want

```
  $saleitemlist=array("555_red, 305_black, 582_elecblue, 593_black");
```

try

```
 $saleitemlist=array("555_red", "305_black", "582_elecblue", "593_black");
```

its working fine with in_array() [check codepad](http://codepad.org/u7Is4U2s)

Comment: How trivial? Let me try that. I thought PHP uses `,` for Array

Comment: yes but you have put all in `"` so it will behave like string

Comment: I get this error now `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid could you tell me what about you talking its looks fine http://codepad.org/u7Is4U2s

Comment: It is working now. My array was setup with a wrong variable. Thank you so much, repped and marked as an answer friend. Appreciate up reps too.

Answer (score 3):

```
$saleitemlist=array("555_red, 305_black, 582_elecblue, 593_black");
```

This line means that `$saleitemlist` is an array that contains just one elements which is `"555_red, 305_black, 582_elecblue, 593_black"`.

If you want that `555_red` was one elements, `305_black` another and so on. you have to do following:

```
$saleitemlist=array("555_red", "305_black", "582_elecblue", "593_black");
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is wrong:

```
 $saleitemlist=array("555_red, 305_black, 582_elecblue, 593_black");
```

Right one should be this:

```
 $saleitemlist=array("555_red", "305_black", "582_elecblue", "593_black");
```

Each element of array should be wrapped with qutes indivudally.